# Sync a Postgres table between Microservices (Projection, logical replication)

Tags: postgresql, microservices, projection

In a microservice oriented architecture we have the need to "sync" or "project" a table, or part of it, from one to another service near real-time. Given the following scenario:

#### Service A

`SchemaA.account`

```
id   | firstName   | lastName   | createdAt            | deletedAt
1    | Hello       | Name       | 2022-07-05T15:05:39Z | Null
2    | Test        | Name       | 2022-07-05T16:05:39Z | Null
```

#### Service B

`SchemaB.account` should be synced from `SchemaA.account`

```
id   | deletedAt
1    | Null
2    | Null
```

### Terminology

"Projection" is a term primarily used in event-sourced systems, so here a bit misleading. Our source is another relational database (Postgres) as the target. I assume logical replication is the correct term here, but I may be wrong.

### Requirements

1. As you can see I only need to replicate part of table `SchemaA.account`, meaning a subset of the columns.
2. Service B won't have to *write* to that table, just read. So, the sync can be one-way.
3. Solution should be as robust and fault-tolerant as possible. Think of service B being unavailable for some time to receive changes from Service A.
4. If it is a low-level database solution/tool it must be available in AWS RDS.
5. quick! near real-time, not scheduled syncs.

### Possible solutions

I don't want to re-invent the wheel! Most flexibility, I guess, I would have when I use SNS + SQS (e.g. Service A publishes a message on data mutations to SNS, a SQS queue of Service B subscribes and adds data themselve). However, I think this creates alot of overhead.

I am currently lacking the right search terms. The term [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html#:%7E:text=Logical%20replication%20is%20a%20method,byte%2Dby%2Dbyte%20replication.) seems promising at first glance, but I am not sure if the [replication tools](https://www.postgresql.org/download/products/3-clusteringreplication/) are going to solve my cases. I don't want to replicate whole schema for backup clusters but data sync between microservices. [Pglogical](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical) seems also very promising and an [instruction how to enable it in AWS RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/database/part-2-upgrade-your-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-database-using-the-pglogical-extension/) exists.

The question really is that simple: am I on the right track or is there something obvious that I am not considering?

Comment: Why not just connect both services to the same database?

Comment: This is not an option.

Comment: ""Projection" is a term primarily used in event-sourced systems, so here a bit misleading" it's not actually as misleading as you think it is. Under the hood, replication is done by transferring the WAL, which is basically an event based system.

Comment: If all you need is synchronise data between multiple microservices that all uses postgres in the backend, using postgres replication (whether it's physical, logical, or streaming) can be a valid option. It has the drawback that there's very limited option to project data to non postgres database and transforming to a different schema would require additional tools, but if none of those are your concerns, they're much easier to setup than regular event based systems).

Answer (score 1):

The approach that sounds most promising is *Change Data Capture*, which in Postgres leverages the logical replication protocol to capture changes to the data; these changes can then be used to propagate data updates to other services.

For example, one very commonly used tool for implementing CDC in databases like Postgres is Debezium, which has [a guide (no idea if it's current, but it should at least be a start) to using Debezium with RDS Postgres](https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/main/debezium-connector-postgres/RDS.md).  Debezium will publish the changes to Kafka (be careful about the retention settings for topics: the Kafka defaults are often a ticking time bomb for this use case) and some other component will consume the changes from Kafka and, e.g. update the table.

One benefit of this approach is that it means you can introduce a new column into the source database's table without necessarily having to change anything in the destination database: the change consumer will see the new field but it's under no obligation to propagate.

Comment: Had already a look at Debezium and it is in on our list. Thanks for the link. The data transformation part (source and target schema does not need to be the same) is definitely cool, and also a requirement for us. The only problem I have with message-bus-based approaches is: Service B must have CRUD business logic implemented. I would like to have a database-level replication solution but I assume then dead-letter features would not be available out of the box.

Thanks for your answer!